# Perl program can't load modules (CentOS 7)

Tags: perl, centos7

I installed and used the program module-tools on several machines, but this time i can't get it to work (CentOS 7). One Problem is, that i have to call my programs with "perl test.pl" instead of just "test.pl". 
The bigger problem is, that the program doesn't run, it stops with an error.

https://github.com/OTRS/module-tools

```
[root@localhost bin]# sudo -u otrs perl otrs.ModuleTools.pl Module::File::Link
Could not require Console::Command::List:
Attempt to reload Console/BaseCommand.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/parent.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/module-tools/lib/Console/Command/List.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/module-tools/lib/System.pm line 60.
```

Anybody any ideas?

Edit: I installed the dependencies with cpanm.
It also looks like the program runs further as root. It should not run as root, so it closes with an error for that, but it loads the file it can't run as the other user

Edit2:
When i run "perl -V" it get a difference at the end.
Root:

```
Built under linux
  Compiled at Jan 21 2019 22:09:19
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/root/perl5/lib/perl5"
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/root/perl5"
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/root/perl5""
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/root/perl5"
  @INC:
    /root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3
    /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /root/perl5/lib/perl5
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
```

Other User:

```
Built under linux
  Compiled at Jan 21 2019 22:09:19
  @INC:
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    .
```

Could this have something to do with that? Everything else from the output is identical.

RESOLVED!:
I installed the whole vm again, and this time i installed cpanm with

```
sudo yum install "perl(App::cpanminus)"
```

I don't remember how i did that before, but the last time i had to give cpanm a few settings and choose at one point "local::lib" instead of "sudo". I  gues i should have chosen "sudo". But it wirks now, thanks

Comment: *"..that i have to call my programs with "perl test.pl" instead of just "test.pl"..."* Then the shebang of `test.pl` contains a wrong path to the `perl` interpreter I guess?

Comment: *One Problem is, that i have to call my programs with "perl test.pl" instead of just "test.pl".* What happens if you run `test.pl`? What error messages do you see?

Comment: How did you install this tool? Did you clone the Github repo? Or did you just download the program? The program needs libraries which are also included in the repo - so you need to have the whole thing.

Comment: I downloaded the complete zip file and used cpanm for to install the dependencies from the file. The files it's looking for are there, but when the program loads them with "require", it can't find them

Comment: Looks like you have a [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) set up for the root user. You probably installed your modules there (under `~root/perl5`).

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, that gave me the hint i needed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install dependencies from cpanfile. If you have cpanm on your server, you can do it this way:

```
cd ./module-tools
cpanm -l ./deps --installdeps .
perl -I ./deps/lib/perl5/ ./bin/otrs.ModuleTools.pl
```

We can force cpanm to install all dependencies into chooses directory with `-l` flag, and than, we show to interpreter where is all dependencies with `-I ./deps/lib/perl5/`

Comment: You are wrong. Try ``cat ./cpanfile``. And you can check syntax for pl and pm files from module-tools, to detect broken dependencies: ``perl -c ./bin/otrs.ModuleTools.pl``

Comment: Yeah. I see what you mean. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: I installed the dependencies with cpanm. The files it's looking for are there (local program files), but when the program loads them with "require", it can't find them